# Isomorphism Between $U_{h}(\frak{sl}_3)$ and $U({\frak sl}_3)[[h]]$

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups, hopf-algebras

I take the following from Klimyk and Schmudgen's book **Quantum Groups** Page 167:

**Proposition** For $\frak{g}$ a complex semi-simple Lie algebra, there is an isomorphism  $\phi$ of the $h$-adic algebra $U_{h}(\frak{g})$ onto $U({\frak g})[[h]]$ which coincides with the identity map modulo $h$.

Explicitly, for $U_h(\frak{sl}_2)$, the $h$-adic algebra generated by the elements 
$H,E$, and $F$, such that 
$$
[H,E] = 2E, ~~~~~ [H,F] = -2F, ~~~ [E,F] = (e^{h H} - e^{-hH})/(e^h - e^{-h}).
$$
The isomorphism $\phi$ of the 
algebras is uniquely determined by its action on the generating elements and is given by
$$
\phi(H) = H' ~~~~~ \phi(F) = F', ~~~~~ \phi(E) = 2\Big(\frac{\cosh h(H'-1) - 
\cosh 2h\sqrt{C'}}{|H'-1|^2-4C' \sinh^2 h}\Big),
$$
where $H', E',F'$ are the generators of $U(\frak{sl}_2)$ satisfying the relations 
$[H',E'] = 2E'$, $[H',F'] = -2F'$, $[E',F'] = H'$, and $C' = \frac{1}{4}(H'-1)^2 + E'F'$ 
is the Casimir element of $U_h(\frak{sl}_2)$.

I would like to ask if anyone knows of an explicit description of this isomorphism for the case of $\frak{sl}_3$? The reference for the proof of the proposition is Drinfeld's 1986 ICM talk, or Shnider and Sternberg **Quantum Groups** Chapter 11.